# Как сделать ключ для элемента массива в Pickerview?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть `PickerView`, в котором я выбираю пол, мужской или женский
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я обращаюсь в бд по апи и мне  нужно передавать значение 1 или 0
Как сделать так чтобы когда я выбираю мужской пол, в pickerview как бы создавался ключ 1
Есть ли такая возможность у этого компонента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `UIPickerView` есть метод делегата который при скролле берет данные выбранной ячейки.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if row == 0 {
      print("мужской")
    } else if row == 1 {
      print("женский")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо